# Http Status Code. To identify wrong password or wrong username

Tags: flutter, http, validation, http-status-codes

If return 401 (Unauthorized), I don't know password field is wrong or username is wrong in `frontend`.
Which code should return for password wrong? and which code for username wrong?

I wanna know exactly which field is wrong in authentication.

Comment: That might be a bad idea, security-wide. What's next? Password completion?

Answer (score 0):

Usually to identify what happened in backend we send a HTTP code along with some kind of data/message in the body.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. This is not good question. I will delete this post next day.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print parameters value which you send to the Api for better understanding which you send and which response you get. And please make a validation in Email and Password TextFormField because when email and password pattern perfect that after you can send a post request to the backend so you get less error.

Code for parameter printing:

```
Future<http.Response> createUser(String email, String password) {
//Print parameters here for better understanding:
print('params===>{$email && $password}'); 

return http.post(
Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users'),
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{'name': email, 'job': password}),
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. This is not good question. I will delete this post next day.

Comment: application/json does not have a charset parameter.